# Replacing characters in StringBuilder with LinkedHashMap in Java

Tags: java, char, stringbuilder, linkedhashmap

Basically I am writing a program which takes in a large block of text(like an essay), and replaces characters based on two other String lines which are taken in to the program and look like the following:

```
uvxftkbsqpznlcwdeijhoamgyr

etaoinsrhldcumfpgwybvkxjqz
```

The program iterates over the characters in the large block of text, and if a character matches the top lines character it replaces it with the lower character.
I've put the two string lines in to LinkedHashMap for easy access but for some reason the program is not replacing the characters correctly. Here is my code:

```
public class MyReplacer{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileName = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter file name");
    fileName = in.nextLine();
    BufferedReader readerForText = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    Scanner keyFileReader = new Scanner(new File("Key.txt"));
    String topLine = "";
    String bottomLine = "";
    //BufferedReader readerForKeyFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Key.java"));
    StringBuilder fileString = new StringBuilder();

    List<Character> topList = new ArrayList<Character>();

    List<Character> bottomList = new ArrayList<Character>();

    try{
         String line = readerForText.readLine();
         while (line!= null){
             fileString.append(line);
             fileString.append("\n");
             line = readerForText.readLine();
         }
         fileString.toString().toLowerCase();

         System.out.println(fileString);
         topLine = keyFileReader.nextLine();
         bottomLine = keyFileReader.nextLine();


         //Convert top line to char array
         char arrayChar1[] = topLine.toCharArray();
         for(char a:arrayChar1)
         {
            topList.add(a);
         }

         //Convert bottom to char array
         char arrayChar2[] = bottomLine.toCharArray();
         for(char a:arrayChar2)
         {
            bottomList.add(a);
         }


         LinkedHashMap<Character,Character> keyMapper = new LinkedHashMap<Character,Character>();

         for(int i = 0;i<topLine.length();++i)
         {
             keyMapper.put(arrayChar1[i],arrayChar2[i]);
         }

         //Testing that key and value pair has been read in correctly
             for(Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : keyMapper.entrySet())
                {
                    System.out.print(entry.getKey()+  "\n" + entry.getValue());
                }


         //Replace letters in fileString

            for(int x = 0;x<fileString.length();x++)
            {
                for(Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : keyMapper.entrySet())
                {
                    if(fileString.charAt(x)==entry.getKey())
                    {
                        fileString.setCharAt(x,entry.getValue());
                    }

                }
            }
System.out.println(fileString);



     } finally{
         readerForText.close();
         keyFileReader.close();
 }
}
```

A sample of the large text looks like:

```
vkpuu mlusvbxfs
```

However when I replace the character it looks like:

```
wxujj xujzwzkvz
```

Therefore it is not replacing the characters properly

Any explanation as to why its doing this would be great.
Thanks

Comment: And what should it be like ?

Comment: You can also use something like:                                                              for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"))) {
    line.replaceAll("uvxftkbsqpznlcwdeijhoamgyr", "etaoinsrhldcumfpgwybvkxjqz");
}

Comment: @Ritesh no. regex replace doesn't work like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
for(int x = 0;x<fileString.length();x++)
{
    for(Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : keyMapper.entrySet())
    {
        if(fileString.charAt(x)==entry.getKey())
        {
            fileString.setCharAt(x,entry.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```

This should be

```
for(int x = 0;x<fileString.length();x++)
{
    Character c = keyMapper.get(fileString.charAt(x));
    if (c != null)
        fileString.setCharAt(x, c);
}
```

The problem with your way is that by searching through the entries like that you can change a single character more than once.

For example

```
u -> e -> g -> j
```

Answer (score 1):

why you didn't get the right answer?
because this have a inner loop :

```
   for (Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : keyMapper.entrySet()) {
        if (fileString.charAt(x) == entry.getKey()) {
             fileString.setCharAt(x, entry.getValue());
         }
    }
```

consider the first letter at x = 0 ,first it replace v to t , then t to i etc ,
so you can modify to :

```
for (Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : keyMapper.entrySet()) {
 if (fileString.charAt(x) == entry.getKey()) {
     fileString.setCharAt(x, entry.getValue());
     //not need to continue find
     break;
   }
```

}

or simpler :

```
for (int x = 0; x < fileString.length(); x++) {
            if (keyMapper.containsKey(fileString.charAt(x))) {
                fileString.setCharAt(x,     keyMapper.get(fileString.charAt(x)));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating things. Don't fill the StringBuilder then replace chars (just add chars), don't create unnecessary variables, don't loop unnecessarily.

Try this instead:

```
Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < topLine.length(); i++)
    map.put(topLine.charAt(i), bottomLine.charAt(i));
String line = readerForText.readLine();
StringBuilder fileString = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : line.toCharArray())
    fileString.append(map.get(c));
System.out.println(fileString);
```